# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')

Tags: reactjs, antd

So I'm trying to use the custom collapse from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840430/antd-need-to-change-the-background-color-of-collapse-body) and when I include it **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')** problem happened. I have no idea what is going on and it works completely fine on `Codepen`.
Here's the code:
It's basically the same , i just added some icon.

```js
const CustomCollapse = ({props}) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        header={props.header}
        key="1"
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        extra={
          <span>
            <span style={{ color: "#0076de", float: "right" }}>
              {disabled ? <div id="themeBox"><p>+10</p></div> : <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{objectFit:'contain'}} />}
            </span>
          </span>
        }
      >
        {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
    </StyledCollapse>
  );
};
```

Here is where I use the `Collapse`:

```js
<div className={styles.telegramLinks}>
     <AntCollapse header="test">
        <h1>test</h1>
     </AntCollapse>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration of CustomCollapse:

```
const CustomCollapse = ({props}) => {
 // ...
};
```

should be

```
const CustomCollapse = (props) => {
 // ...
 // use `props.header`
};
```

Otherwise it is as if you are looking for an attribute named `props` on the component, that is, a props with the name `props`.

Alternatively you can declare:

```
const CustomCollapse = ({ header }) => {
 // ...
 // use `header` directly instead of `props.header` 
};
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! I wrote `({props})` because I have a red line saying `Must use destructuring props assignment` so I added curly braces to remove the error, didnt know that it would make the thing to not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to get props this way you need to use :

```
const CustomCollapse = (props) => {
```

instead of

```
const CustomCollapse = ({props}) => {
```